# Predict the Product(s) of a reaction of tertiary benzylic alkyl halide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I could find two products:
The first one where is $\ce{Cl}$ is replaced by $\ce{CN}$.
AND the second one where $\ce{CH3CH2O}$ replaces $\ce{Cl}$.
Did I make a mistake or miss anyone?

Comment: What about elimination?

Comment: Ok, so there would be another two that are alkenes.

Comment: OUPS, three others.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{CN-}$ is a significantly stronger nucleophile than $\ce{EtOH}$ and will therefore primarily displace the chloride. The facts that substitution takes place at a tertiary benzylic carbon, and that a polar protic solvent (ethanol) is used indicate that the reaction follows the $\ce{S_{N}1}$ mechanism (sources: [1](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhighered.mheducation.com%2Fsites%2Fdl%2Ffree%2F0073402745%2F990527%2Fsample_chapter.pdf&ei=FUJZVJLUOIzXarqcgegI&usg=AFQjCNGWAs8cJBU0l2Xy52elFQrzImeYqA), [2](http://pages.towson.edu/ladon/orgrxs/reagent/bases.htm), [3](http://www.wikipremed.com/03_organicmechanisms.php?mch_code=030204_030)). Due to the achiral intermediate (carbocation), the nitrile will be obtained as a racemic mixture, i.e. 2 products.

[Elimination](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/alhalrx3.htm) is also a possible reaction pathway which needs to be considered, since cyanide is a good nucleophile but a weak base, which favors an [E2 reaction](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/11/30/deciding-sn1sn2e1e2-2-the-nucleophilebase/) unless an excess of $\ce{CN-}$ is present. In this case, the product with the more substituted double bond should be favored.

Answer (score 0):

nucleophilicity $CN->I->EtO-$ which implies cyanide attacks, no heating means no elimination generally